# dll debug in C language

Tags: c, dll, debugging

I want to debug one api call of dll?
It is written in C language.
I do not know the calling process,so I need to write one process which can call api of above dll?
I am using VS 2005.
Can I get help for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create application project who calling api from this dll and you can simple add breakpoints in your dll function code or something else you want to debug this.